# How to make C++ wrapper of C# DLL COM InterOp method?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wrapper

I have a C# COM DLL and I want to call its methods throught c++ methods.

How do I make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask VisualStudio to generate the typelib or use [`regasm.exe /tlb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) to generate the typelib, then import it into the C++ project with [`#import` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: After importing the generated tlb, how can I access to the functions. Can you give me some code example plz

Comment: After importing the typelib you get a bunch of interfaces in it. Use those interfaces. Use CoCreateInstance() to instantiate objects.

Comment: Check the MSDN docs for the _com_ptr_t class, that's the base class for the smart interface pointers.